# RagTag patch error--"Tuple index out of range"

Tags: assembly, scaffold, ragtag

*This question was also asked on [GitHub](https://github.com/malonge/RagTag/issues/152)*

I'm trying to correct a long-read assembly with a short-read scaffold; I'm hoping to fill in the short gaps in the scaffold with the matching long-read sections. The RagTag "patch" function, if I understand correctly, is supposed to do exactly this. I use this command:

```
ragtag.py patch --fill-only liberibacter_central_ragtag.fasta liberibacter_central_assembly.fasta
```

But when I attempt to run it I get the following error:

```
Tue Feb  7 09:55:17 2023 --- VERSION: RagTag v2.1.0
Tue Feb  7 09:55:17 2023 --- WARNING: This is a beta version of `ragtag patch`
Tue Feb  7 09:55:17 2023 --- CMD: ragtag.py patch --fill-only liberibacter_central_assembly.fasta liberibacter_central_ragtag.fasta
Tue Feb  7 09:55:17 2023 --- WARNING: Without '-u' invoked, some component/object AGP pairs might share the same ID. Some external programs/databases don't like this. To ensure valid AGP format, use '-u'.
Tue Feb  7 09:55:17 2023 --- INFO: Running: ragtag_splitasm.py -o /xdisk/baltrus/moshesteyn/ragtag_output/ragtag.patch.ctg.agp /xdisk/baltrus/moshesteyn/liberibacter_central_assembly.fasta > /xdisk/baltrus/moshesteyn/ragtag_output/ragtag.patch.ctg.fasta 2> /xdisk/baltrus/moshesteyn/ragtag_output/ragtag.patch.err
Tue Feb  7 09:55:17 2023 --- INFO: Finished running : ragtag_splitasm.py -o /xdisk/baltrus/moshesteyn/ragtag_output/ragtag.patch.ctg.agp /xdisk/baltrus/moshesteyn/liberibacter_central_assembly.fasta > /xdisk/baltrus/moshesteyn/ragtag_output/ragtag.patch.ctg.fasta 2> /xdisk/baltrus/moshesteyn/ragtag_output/ragtag.patch.err
Tue Feb  7 09:55:17 2023 --- INFO: Running: ragtag_rename.py /xdisk/baltrus/moshesteyn/liberibacter_central_ragtag.fasta -p qseq -o /xdisk/baltrus/moshesteyn/ragtag_output/ragtag.patch.rename.agp > /xdisk/baltrus/moshesteyn/ragtag_output/ragtag.patch.rename.fasta 2> /xdisk/baltrus/moshesteyn/ragtag_output/ragtag.patch.err
Tue Feb  7 09:55:17 2023 --- INFO: Finished running : ragtag_rename.py /xdisk/baltrus/moshesteyn/liberibacter_central_ragtag.fasta -p qseq -o /xdisk/baltrus/moshesteyn/ragtag_output/ragtag.patch.rename.agp > /xdisk/baltrus/moshesteyn/ragtag_output/ragtag.patch.rename.fasta 2> /xdisk/baltrus/moshesteyn/ragtag_output/ragtag.patch.err
Tue Feb  7 09:55:17 2023 --- INFO: Writing: /xdisk/baltrus/moshesteyn/ragtag_output/ragtag.patch.comps.fasta
Tue Feb  7 09:55:17 2023 --- INFO: Mapping the query genome to the target genome
Tue Feb  7 09:55:17 2023 --- INFO: Running: nucmer --maxmatch -l 100 -c 500 -p /xdisk/baltrus/moshesteyn/ragtag_output/ragtag.patch.asm /xdisk/baltrus/moshesteyn/ragtag_output/ragtag.patch.ctg.fasta /xdisk/baltrus/moshesteyn/ragtag_output/ragtag.patch.rename.fasta 2> /xdisk/baltrus/moshesteyn/ragtag_output/ragtag.patch.asm.delta.log
Tue Feb  7 09:55:19 2023 --- INFO: Finished running : nucmer --maxmatch -l 100 -c 500 -p /xdisk/baltrus/moshesteyn/ragtag_output/ragtag.patch.asm /xdisk/baltrus/moshesteyn/ragtag_output/ragtag.patch.ctg.fasta /xdisk/baltrus/moshesteyn/ragtag_output/ragtag.patch.rename.fasta > /xdisk/baltrus/moshesteyn/ragtag_output/ragtag.patch.asm.delta.log
Tue Feb  7 09:55:19 2023 --- INFO: Running: ragtag_delta2paf.py /xdisk/baltrus/moshesteyn/ragtag_output/ragtag.patch.asm.delta > /xdisk/baltrus/moshesteyn/ragtag_output/ragtag.patch.asm.paf 2> /xdisk/baltrus/moshesteyn/ragtag_output/ragtag.patch.err
Tue Feb  7 09:55:19 2023 --- INFO: Finished running : ragtag_delta2paf.py /xdisk/baltrus/moshesteyn/ragtag_output/ragtag.patch.asm.delta > /xdisk/baltrus/moshesteyn/ragtag_output/ragtag.patch.asm.paf 2> /xdisk/baltrus/moshesteyn/ragtag_output/ragtag.patch.err
Tue Feb  7 09:55:19 2023 --- INFO: Reading whole genome alignments
Tue Feb  7 09:55:19 2023 --- INFO: Filtering and merging alignments
Tue Feb  7 09:55:19 2023 --- INFO: Building a scaffold graph from the contig AGP file
Tue Feb  7 09:55:19 2023 --- INFO: Building a scaffold graph from the target/query mappings
Tue Feb  7 09:55:19 2023 --- INFO: Computing a matching solution to the scaffold graph
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/u30/moshesteyn/.conda/envs/py382/bin/ragtag_patch.py", line 518, in <module>
    main()
File "/home/u30/moshesteyn/.conda/envs/py382/bin/ragtag_patch.py", line 497, in main
    match_psg = aln_psg.max_weight_matching()
File "/home/u30/moshesteyn/.conda/envs/py382/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ragtag_utilities/ScaffoldGraph.py", line 824, in max_weight_matching
    for cc in nx.connected_components(G=cover_graph):
File "/home/u30/moshesteyn/.conda/envs/py382/lib/python3.8/site-packages/networkx/classes/backends.py", line 134, in wrapper
    graph = args[0]
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Does anyone know what might be causing this error? No one else seems to have run into it on the github. I've run it with both files individually against a known reference, as well as reversing the order of the files and removing the "fill-only" option, and I have the same problem. I've looked at several of the output files, and they seem normal, at least in that they aren't empty or filled with zeroes.

Comment: Were any errors/warnings logged in any of the `*.err` or `*.log` files (in the _ragtag_output_ folder)?

Comment: The output mentions potential AGP issues if not using `-u`; have you tried running it with `-u` included?

Comment: Can you post some assembly stats for your various assemblies? I could imagine that a filtering process under the hood removes some small artefactual contigs and exposes some sort of edge case, but it's not totally clear from what you've shown so far. For example, do you have any tiny short-read contigs that are all `GGGG` or something?

Comment: @Steve no errors noted in the .log, and .err is empty.

Comment: -u makes no difference, and the shortest contigs are non-repetitive between 190 and 600 bp. What kinds of stats are you looking for--spades log?

Comment: Sorry to spam the comments. Attempting to run my own patch, I've mapped the contigs individually to the reference, but for two short ones Bowtie doesn't find matches at all. Might this be causing the problem?

Comment: @schmiggle you will need to use `@` to tag us when you comment, or we won't see it. Yes, any sort of stats on the assembly would be helpful, spades/quast would be fine. I doubt that the issue is a failure to find a match as that is likely a common case. I'd suggest simply filtering out contigs <500bp because they are unlikely to be very informative.